# PhpStorm, return value is expected to be 'A', 'object' returned

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have this:

```php
class A {}
class B {}

class X
{
    private function create(string $class) : object
    {
        return new $class();
    }
    
    public function createA() : A
    {
        return $this->create('A');
    }

    public function createB() : B
    {
        return $this->create('B');
    }
}
```

And as the screenshot says:

[image]

What to set for return type to indicate that it is an "object"? Unfortunately `A` and `B` don't have anything in common (except that THEY BOTH ARE OBJECTS!!!!)

Comment: Looks good to me as an `object` return type. https://3v4l.org/5fECj And it also looks good with explicity `A|B` union return type. https://3v4l.org/1pvYL  Report it to PHPStorm if you don't like it.  Or are you actually asking for `A|B` as an answer?  What PHP version are you using (and what version does PHPStorm think you are using)?

Comment: What happens if you just return objects? Like this: https://3v4l.org/B55mQ

Comment: Basically RUN the code, dont rely upon a pre-compiler

Comment: it works well, its not a problem. But it bothers me that it is higlighted with red color...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has to be because `object` can be ANY class instance, even `B` etc.

You can annotate the `create()` method with generics PHPDoc to tell that the return type will be the same as the input parameter class string. It gives more context info to the IDE.

```php
    /**
     * @template T
     *
     * @param string $class
     * @return T
     */
    private function create(string $class) : object
    {
        return new $class();
    }
```

[image]

**P.S.**

Instead of `create('B');` better use `create(B::class)`. This way the IDE can track the usages of that class for refactoring/search purposes etc.